# SQL Queries Stacking causing DB to crash

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, debugging

So I have a website running, and according to the shared hosting admin, there are some SQL queries that are stacking and causing the DB to crash. It's shared hosting, so they can't tell me much because of security issues, etc.

Is there any way to debug this on my own machine and track down these errors?

I'm not sure where the queries are coming from. I suspect it might be the data-entity framework, or maybe the POCO objects.

Any ideas on how to debug or where you suspect these errors are originating would be great. I've searched a bit and can't find much on where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: *SQL queries that are stacking and causing the DB to crash* you would have to define what you mean here, since you are inventing new terms. There is no such term as 'query stacking'. Also, specify what 'crash' means. Deadlock? Timeout? Core dump? Do you have an error number and an error message?

Comment: Thanks for asking for clarification. Um, to tell the truth I'm not entirely sure. Support for the hosting used these terms. They said that the site starts out with 2 or 3 queries, then jumps to over 40, causing the database to crash. Unfortunately since I'm not the admin, I have no access to error messages or error logging.

Comment: I guess what I need is information on how to run sql debugging on my website to find out when and where queries are happening so I can go inspect them. I'm just a newbie when it comes to the Microsoft development environment and packages

Comment: I would suggest that if your host can't handle 40 simlutaneous queries, they are incompetent and/or under equipped and should be replaced. If they can't give you the information you need to solve a problem, then they are definietly not someone you want having control of your business critical data. ANd using a term like query stacking, which as a database professional with 30 years of experience I have never heard, suggests extreme incompetence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a local SQL Server environment to test? Running a Trace in SQL Profiler is what you need, but you may not be able to simulate the volume. At least you can see the SQL code different parts of your app are creating.

Comment: Thanks, I'm replicating the database so I can connect to it locally and run traces. Thanks for the info!